# What is the relationship between the Monitor from "Crisis on Infinite Earths" and the Monitors from "Final Crisis"?

Tags: dc

In *Crisis on Infinite Earths*, there is a character called the Monitor (Mar Novu) who comes into existence when someone views the moment of creation, and fractures the universe creating multiverses.

In *Final Crisis*, there is a race of Monitors, which seem to have nothing to do with the Monitor from CoIE.

What is the relationship between all the different types of Monitors in DC? Including the Over-Monitor, Mandrakk, and the Monitor created by Perpetua.

Comment: I swear this is a dupe. Can't find it though